# Compile error wso2 ESB 4.8.1. and kernel

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are having problems compiling kernel wso2 esb and wso2 
Jdk -> jdk1.7.0_60

**Error wso2 esb 4.8.1**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project org.wso2.esb.integration.core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.wso2.esb:org.wso2.esb.integration.core:jar:4.8.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.11-wso2v6 in wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project org.wso2.esb.integration.core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.wso2.esb:org.wso2.esb.integration.core:jar:4.8.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.11-wso2v6 in wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/)
```

**Error wso2carbon-kernel 4.2.0**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.1:compile (default-compile) on project wss4j: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /sources/wso2/wso2carbon-kernel/dependencies/wss4j/1.5.11-wso2v6/src/org/apache/ws/security/kerberos/KrbTicketDecoder.java:[10,24] EncryptionKey is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[ERROR]
```

A greeting and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use JDK 1.6 to build the WSO2 platform. Please check WSO2 docs from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Installation+Prerequisites)

> If you want to build the product from the source distribution, you
>   must use JDK 1.6 instead of JDK 1.7.

But it says that you can run the product on JDK 1.7

> Oracle and IBM JRE 1.7 are also supported when running (not building)
>   WSO2 products.

Answer (score 0):

As Asela mentioned kernal switch to java 1.6 and for the ESB failure, you can build [1] to get rid of that issue.

[1]-http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/patch0002/dependencies/wss4j/1.5.11-wso2v6/